# how to change the fontSize in a select tag?

Tags: html, css

when I change to iPad Pro screen size, the words in the select tag can't be seen exactly?

how to resolve ???

thx!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qBra.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make certain elements responsive you can us `@media` like so.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1035px) {
    .navbar a {
        padding: 14px 12%;
    }
}
```

This will change any defined classes that are under a screen `width` of `1035px` for example. Change the pixels to change the `width`.